# Convert dynamic backend to modules in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

I want to convert my backends.xml as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<backends>
    <backend name="backendfirst">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
        </options>
    </backend>
    <backend name="backendsecond">
        <class>B1</class>
        <options>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
            <public>true</public>
        </options>
    </backend>
</backends>
```

Into modules in Java. How can I do this? I saw the documentation about converting backends.xml to module, but I didn't see any option for making it dynamic or public.

Thanks.

Comment: So, based on this doc: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting could you please describe more precisely the things that don't work for you?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the respond. I know that for making it dynamic we can use **basic-scaling** element in the module xml. But how about the equivalent **public** element in backend for the module xml? Because by default backend is always private. Thanks

Comment: Modules can be accessed directly if you want or via routing. Here's the documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing

Comment: You can then make a module accessible publicly, require authentication or allow only admins to access the module. The same level of access that you can use for the application.

Comment: So which element that I can use to define this accessibility in module? Or I just need to give this on **security-constraint** element in web.xml? thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can use security-constraint of the module.